How to track utm parameters from pardot salesforce forms?
I am new to salesforce and GA. I have created a custom redirect for my contact form. I have a form that has hidden utm fields. It has a layout template and as per my understanding I have to copy the html source of the form and add it to the html body in layout template. I would like to know where exactly I need to copy and paste the script? I got the info via this article - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383147&type=1. I do not have access to the website's code but I have access to our GA4 and google tag manager.
I tried adding the code in this article - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383147&type=1
<noscript>
 <iframe src="PARDOT_FORM_URL" width="100%" height="500" type="text/html" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border: 0"></iframe>
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var form = 'PARDOT_FORM_URL';
 var params = window.location.search;
 var thisScript = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
 var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

 iframe.setAttribute('src', form + params);
 iframe.setAttribute('width', '100%');
 iframe.setAttribute('height', 500);
 iframe.setAttribute('type', 'text/html');
 iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', 0);
 iframe.setAttribute('allowTransparency', 'true');
 iframe.style.border = '0';

 thisScript.parentElement.replaceChild(iframe, thisScript);
</script>

into landing form but when i see preview changes- It shows just the iframe again. I don't want multiple iframes.
